# Running pip causes deadlock

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

When I run pip install or only pip from Windows Command Line, I think that it causes deadlock and it's impossible to exit running process by pressing **CTRL + C**

When I run it from Git Bash, it gives me errors

`0 [sig] bash 9796 get_proc_lock: Couldn't acquire sync_proc_subproc for(5,1), last 7, Win32 error 0`

`1040 [sig] bash 9796 proc_subproc: couldn't get proc lock. what 5, val 1`

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it. Solution is to call pip as a python module.

1. Remove `pip.exe, pip3.exe, pip3.5.exe` from `PYTHON_PATH/Scripts`
2. Create file `pip.bat` inside folder described above
3. Open pip.bat in text editor and copy lines below to it

`@echo off 
call "python" -m pip %*`

Answer (score 0):

As per https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip

try from CMD.

On Linux or OS X:

```
pip install -U pip
```

On Windows:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```